# Как передать переменную от ребенка к родителю?

Tags: vue.js

Есть страница внутри которой есть два таба с отдельными компонентами - таблицами.
В зависимости от того, какая таблица открыта нужно показывать именно на странице (в род. компоненте) кол-во записей (не в самом компоненте с таблицей). Можно ли передавать переменную через emit?
Если нет, то как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Можно через emit спокойно передавать. Читайте документацию, там всё описано и расписано: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#event-arguments

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, я могу подписаться на emit только в самом компоненте таблице внутри родительского компонента. а как мне теперь вывести его в род компоненте?
`<partner-users @get-rows-count="showRowsCount" />`
`const showRowsCount = (n: number) => {
  console.log('n')
}`

Comment: Переменные, и выводите по переменной (условие или само значение) что хотите. Если я Вас правильно понял